# (Wrong)Redirect to Login page instead submitting record MVC c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a login page and another page that has a submit button.

When inputting record and clicking submit instead of processing action, it automatically redirects to login page.

MVC View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <input type="button" value="Download PDF" class="btn btn-lg w-100 bg-primary text-white" id="DownloadPDF" />
    <label class="small disclaimerText">Please input your name</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#DownloadPDF').click(function (e) {
    alert("clicking download");
    --just code for download pdf
}
```

Adding console log. It appears that it is still going to function but still redirect to login page.

Comment: In your js function add `e.preventdefault()`

Comment: Your button is submitting the form, change to `<button type='button'` or `return false` from event handler (or preventDefault as above)